# Why is MySQL float different than Java float?

Tags: java, mysql, floating-point

I insert a float value 1223473 in a MySQL float column and the value changes to 1223470 when I get it back.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        try {
            // SETUP
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://...");

            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ttt");

            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE ttt (value FLOAT)");

            // INPUT VALUE
            float input = 1.223473E6f;
            print(" Input", input);
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO ttt VALUES (?)");
            pstmt.setFloat(1, input);
            pstmt.execute();

            // OUTPUT VALUES
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT value, "
                    + "AVG(value) as avg, MIN(value) as min, "
                    + "MAX(value) as max, value + 0 as plus, "
                    + "value * 1 as mult, "
                    + "cast(value as decimal) as valcast "
                    + "FROM ttt;");
            rs.next();
            System.out.println();
            print("Output", rs.getFloat("value"));
            print("   AVG", rs.getFloat("avg"));
            print("   MIN", rs.getFloat("min"));
            print("   MAX", rs.getFloat("max"));
            print("    +0", rs.getFloat("plus"));
            print("    *1", rs.getFloat("mult"));
            print("  CAST", rs.getFloat("valcast"));

        } finally {
            if (stmt != null)
                stmt.close();
            if (pstmt != null)
                pstmt.close();
            if (conn != null)
                conn.close();
        }

    }

    private static void print(String name, float value) {
        System.out.println(name + ": " + value + " (0x" 
            + Integer.toHexString(Float.floatToRawIntBits(value)) + ")");
    }
```

Here is the output:

```
 Input: 1223473.0 (0x49955988)

Output: 1223470.0 (0x49955970)
   AVG: 1223473.0 (0x49955988)
   MIN: 1223473.0 (0x49955988)
   MAX: 1223473.0 (0x49955988)
    +0: 1223473.0 (0x49955988)
    *1: 1223473.0 (0x49955988)
  CAST: 1223473.0 (0x49955988)
```

The same behavior is seen using the MySQL client.

I was unable to explain why the input value is not the same as the output. Moreover, why applying an operation give the right value?  Even with other values I get the same behavior. For example if I use 1223472 instead of 122473, the output value will be 1223470. It looks like a lost of precision. But why applying an operation on it return exactly the input value ? It looks like MySQL stores more precision than what it shows.

It does not look like the typical misunderstanding about floating point types where people try to put too many digits in a float:

```
System.out.println(1223473f == 1223470f);  // gives false
System.out.println(123456789f == 123456791f);  // gives true (too many digits)
```

Finally, I don't know what to think about that...

```
mysql> create table ttt (value float);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO ttt VALUES (1223473);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from ttt;
+---------+
| value   |
+---------+
| 1223470 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM ttt WHERE value = 1223470;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM ttt WHERE value = 1223473;
+---------+
| value   |
+---------+
| 1223470 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why the value changes ?

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `float` as a data type.  You don't have enough precision to represent 1223473.0.  Floating point numbers are also subject to "platform or implementation dependencies" per the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html).

Change the data type on the column to `double` (or `decimal`) and that should resolve your problem.  See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a28588/1) for confirmation.

Aggregate functions like [SUM, AVG, return a `double`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) value when performed on values of `float` or `double`.  It isn't clear from the documentation, but I strongly suspect that when that this is also the case when using `MIN`, `MAX`, `+ 0` or `* 1` also results in a data type that can "hold the resulting value".

You should be aware floating point operations should be conducted within a [*tolerance*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html) (i.e., threshold), also as specified by the MySQL documentation.

Comment: I agree it seems the MySQL float has not enough precision even if the Java float has enough to represent this number.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the initial value comes back when applying an operation on it. I edited my question to better show this.

Comment: Added some additional info.  For SUM, AVG: These functions return a double.  I strongly suspect that data that can "hold the result" is returned with the others.  If you change the double to a `float(8,1)` then that will also resolve your issue.  Bottom line: when using floating point types, ensure that you have a data type that is large enough to hold your values, otherwise use a `decimal`